# Convert a Char Matrix to Numeric, avoiding display in scientific notation

Tags: r, matrix

I have a pretty large dataset of coordinates. When I imported them, R turned them into characters. When I try converting my matrix into a numeric one, R turns my longitudinal values into scientific notation.

As an example,

```
head(locations)

        Long         Lat       
[1,] "-120.5215"  "34.5318" 
[2,] "-120.86726" "35.36824"
[3,] "-120.86726" "35.36824"
[4,] "-120.86726" "35.36824"
```

using the as.numeric function R returns my longitudinal values to scientific notation.

```
locations <- apply(locations,  c(1, 2),as.numeric)
head(locations)

         Long       Lat
  [1,] -1.205215e+02 34.53180
  [2,] -1.208673e+02 35.36824
  [3,] -1.208673e+02 35.36824
  [4,] -1.208673e+02 35.36824
```

How can I get R to turn this non-numeric matrix into a numeric one **WITHOUT** it screwing up the coordinate format?

Comment: Can you show a sampling of what R returns?

Comment: `mode(test) <- "numeric"`

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell, Hello, I have edited my question and added more details. Thank you for taking time to help. As you can see, using the as.numeric function will mess up the format of my longitudinal values. And for mapping purposes, the package I'm using doesn't accept scientific notation formats.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell, hello again! I think I figured it out. There was one longitudinal value with a missing decimal point (making the number really large), so R re-formatted the rest of the coordinates using scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! In case anybody else is having the same problem this is the code that I used:

```
>test #non-numeric matrix
    long        lat      
[1,] "-112.16442" "39.5934" 
[2,] "-110.61798" "35.76698"
[3,] "-110.20331" "39.87408"

>apply(test, 2,as.numeric) #Numeric-matrix

         longs     lats
[1,] -122.1644 37.29340
[2,] -120.6180 37.76898
[3,] -121.2033 34.86808
```

And it didn't ruin the format. Yey.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but this question & answer won't likely help anyone unless you edit your question to provide more details about what specifically you tried with `as.numeric`, what the exact output was, and why it wasn't correct. I suspect the problem was simply that `as.numeric` dropped the dimensions and returned a vector rather than a matrix.